# How to justify text in text-field control in editable PDF using C# iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2015, itext

I am using iTextSharp to fill PDF. I have textfield and I am inserting 4-5 lines of text in textfield programmatically. Text lines are not properly aligned. I kept it as left aligned as textfield has only 3 options for alignment (left,right,center). How to justify text in PDF. I am using Nitro PDF software to edit files.

Please suggest with an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone has comment on this?

Comment: Why iTextSharp doesn't support Justify alignment?

Comment: It appears like there is no quadding support in generated appearances in iText 5.x.